# Adding an external script to Gatsby with the help of a plugin `gatsby-plugin-makerwidget` is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Yesterday I tried adding https://makerwidget.com to my website & at the end of customising it I get a script tag which I want to add to my website

The script is -

```
<script>
    (function(d, h, m){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(h)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(m)){return;}
        js = d.createElement(h); js.id = m;
        js.onload = function(){
            window.makerWidgetComInit({
            position: "left",          
            widget: "2hc0aqfnigsyxkf5-aewnonydaddchdgj-vwoc6njlwhycxyw6"                
        })};
        js.src = "https://makerwidget.com/js/embed.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
    }(document, "script", "dhm"))
</script>
```

I want to add it as a plugin with 2 options -

(1) `position` which is `left`

(2) `widgetId` which is `2hc0aqfnigsyxkf5-aewnonydaddchdgj-vwoc6njlwhycxyw6`

I released v1.0.0 at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/gatsby-plugin-makerwidget which has no options & its written like [gatsby-plugin-twitter](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-twitter) but doesn't work

How do I make it add an external script?

And how do I add 2 options position & widgetId to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution

I mistakenly put `gatsby-browser.js` in `src/` folder rather than keeping it on top level

Everything else works fine :)